# Given n mod 2 = 1 and n mod 3 =1. Find n mod 5. How to solve algebraically knowing n = 7

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know that n = 7, so I should expect a remainder of 2 when divided by 5. However, finding the solution algebraically gives me a wrong remainder of 6. Please help me find my errors, or even find a better way to approach this problem. My work is shown below. $$$$
I know that a general solution involves finding n in terms of the equations:
$$ n = 2k + 1$$
$$n = 3m +1$$
I try to make both equations have a divisor of 5 like this:
$$\frac{5}{2}n = 5k + \frac{5}{2}$$ and
$$\frac{5}{3}n = 5m + \frac{5}{3}$$
I try to find the value of n by noticing $n = \frac{5}{2}n -\frac{9}{10} \cdot(\frac{5}{3}n)$.
$$n = (5k + \frac{5}{2}) - \frac{9}{10}\cdot(5m + \frac{5}{3})$$
This becomes $$n = (5k - 5m\cdot \frac{9}{10})+ (\frac{5}{2} -\frac{5}{3}\cdot\frac{9}
{10})$$
When I simplify this I get $$n = 5(k-\frac{9m}{10})+1$$
I note that $1 = -5 + 6$, therefore
$$n = 5(k-\frac{9m}{10}) -5 +6$$
So in the end $$n = 5(k-\frac{9m}{10} -1) +6$$
I get a remainder of 6 but I was expecting a remainder of 2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $\frac{9m}{10}$ is an integer? Also, the two conditions you have - $n = 1 mod 2, n = 1 mod 3$ do not give a unique solution, i.e. 7 is not the only solution arising from these conditions

Comment: Since $2$ and $3$ are both coprime to $5$, the initial modular identities don’t tell you anything about $x \bmod 5$. They do tell you by the Chinese remainder theorem that $x\equiv 1\bmod 6$ .

Comment: I'm assuming that everything within the brackets is an integer. So I assume n = 5x + 6. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, because when you assumed that $n =3m+1$, $m$ was any integer, not necessarily divisible by 10. Therefore, you cannot say with certainty that $\frac{9m}{10}$ is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n$ could be $1,7,13,19$ or $25$, so $n\pmod5$ could be $1,2,3,4$ or $0$.

Comment: i.e. $\bmod 5\!:\  n = 1+6k \equiv 1+k\,$ takes *all* values, i.e. is surjective (onto).

Answer (score 3):

So I'm a bit confused, $6k+1$ is a solution of $n mod2 =1$ and $n mod3 =1$. So the solution isn't unique unless I'm missing something. Once you tell me that it is 7 then the earlier hypotheses are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You've helped me realize that the solution cannot be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Every odd integer is of the form $2k+1$.

When you say that $n = 3k+1$, you mean that $n$ is an odd integer which gives remainder $1$ when divided by $3$.

Thus, you mean that $n$ is of the form $6k+1$.

This means that:

$$n = 5k + k + 1$$
$$n = k+1(mod 5)$$

Thus the expected set of remainders must be:$$remainder = {0,1,2,3,4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad you understood